# Assassin's Creed 2 occasionaly closes silently when autosaving

Tags: pc, technical-issues, assassins-creed-2

Sometimes when I do something that would cause an autosave (loot a chest, pick up a feather, accept a mission), the game silently quits, no errors messages or anything. My PC has a quadcore CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with AC2 running on multicore CPUs. If you suffer from this bug, you need to set the game's CPU affinity to limit it to 2 cores. To do so, open the task manager after launching the game, find `AssassinsCreedIIGame.exe` in the task manager's processes tab right click it, click on **Set affinity** and uncheck all but 2 items in the list.

You can also launch the game with the correct affinity settings set every time by creating a custom shortcut. Make a shortcut to `AssassinsCreedIIGame.exe`, then edit its target to be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /affinity 5 AssassinsCreedIIGame.exe` (/affinity 5 sets CPU affinity to CPU 0 + CPU 2).

If the issue persists, or if you are encountering it on a dualcore system, you can set CPU affinity to only 1 core; in this case replace `/affinity 5` with `/affinity 1` or `/affinity 2` in your shortcut if you choose to make one.

Comment: `This is a known issue with AC2 running on multicore CPUs.` You mean "*CPUs with more than 2 cores*", right? As far as I know, multicore CPUs are the minimum required to play the even older AC1.

Comment: @Nolonar possibly, I haven't tried running AC2 on every multicore CPU on the market. I'm pretty sure no game **requires** a multicore CPU, though running a single core at clocks necessary for some games may require custom hardware and liquid nitrogen cooling or better.